# How can I use JavaScript code in Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, materialize, angular7

I'm trying to make a collapsible navbar with the help of MaterializeCSS when used on mobile screen and need to use JavaScript code in it.
Where should I write this JavaScript code?

This is the code I want to use:

```
**$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
  });**
```

Comment: you should write in the component file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Step-1: Created a js folder inside the assets folder.

Step-2: Created a new .js file inside the js folder. Assets -> js -> example.js

Step-3: Added path of the example.js in angular.json inside the scripts array.

Step-4: Declared the js function created in example.js inside the component.ts file where that function is needed.

Step-5: Made a call to the declared function inside ngOnInIt().

Answer (score 4):

1. Install jQuery `npm install jquery`
2. Install MaterializeCSS `npm install materialize-css@next`
3. Install types `npm install --save @types/materialize-css @types/jquery`
4. Open `angular.json` and find `scripts` field
5. Add `node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` and `node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js` inside array:

> ```
> "scripts": [
>     "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
>     "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"
> ]
> ```

6. Go to your component and add at the top `declare var jQuery: any;`

#### Example

```
(function ($) {
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
})(jQuery);
```

You can use that inside `ngOnInit`.

Comment: getting this error **TypeError: $(...).sidenav is not a function**

Comment: I already have materialize script inside the array and still getting the same error

Comment: Did you install types? And in `angular.json` there are 2 `scripts` fields.

Comment: Yeah, I did both.

Comment: Make sure that jQuery is first in array, then MaterializeCSS. And changes in `angular.json` require you to restart webservice. So just stop and start angular again. @harshitraghav

Comment: Looks like you need to pass arguments to that function. https://materializecss.com/sidenav.html#methods

Comment: What should i pass as an argument in this case?

Comment: Sorry, no idea, documentation doesn't say anything about that. Pass any string and see if error still occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Find and open `angular.json`, then add to `projects.architect.build.options` object next field and change filepath to your own:

```
"scripts": [
  "path/to/js/you/want/use.js"
]
```

Angular will add those custom files to result build

Comment: I have created a file and added it's path like you said but how to use it inside the component?