# Add JavaScript library/code in Angular CLI

Tags: javascript, angular-cli

I am trying to use the Typed.js library in Angular CLI, but I couldn't manage to make it work. I followed the instructions in *[How can I use JavaScript code in Angular 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53482324/how-can-i-use-javascript-code-in-angular-7][1])*: copied the jQuery library and typed scrips in assets folder, added a path to the files in angular.json, but I am not sure what to do in the component.ts file:

This is my component.ts code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var jQuery: any;
declare var Typed: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-typing',
  templateUrl: './typing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./typing.component.scss']
})
export class TypingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    var typed = new Typed('.typed', {
      strings: ["First sentence.", "Second sentence."],
      typeSpeed: 30
    });
  }

  onComplete() {
  }

}
```

I am pretty sure what I wrote in ngOnInit() is wrong, but how can I make it right?

Comment: Try to import this way : `import * as typed from Typed.js'; ` And after you can use it with `typed` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import `typed.js` in order to be able to use it. Declaring it as variable with type of `any` does not make any sense. Try importing it instead like this:
`import Typed from 'typed.js';`

Comment: the import command doesn t work. It says it cannot find any module there.

Comment: Did you install `typed.js` using `npm install typed.js` or with other package manager?